# Python: how to format facebook date (ISO 8601) in jinja2?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, flask, jinja2, iso8601

While creating flask app to show facebook events data I've encountered a problem with event['start_time'] (facebook-graph-api) object formatting. When trying to format object in jinja placeholder in my index.html file I get an error: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'datetime' is undefined. Libraries imported in app.py)

What I've already tried was formatting event['start_date'] in app.py and pasting it to render_template which formatted the date correctly but printed only first input under every event in flask for loop.

Also looking for other solutions I was trying to use dateutil.parser.parse on event['start_time']  filter with similar to first error- dateutil is undefined. Using strftime on event['start_time'] and applying filter based on strftime gave me an error 'str object' has no attribute 'strftime'.

So it looks like I'm not getting those libraries from app.py in jinja or it has something to do with event['start_time'] format.

Thank you in advance for any clues :)

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import json
import facebook
import datetime
from time import strptime, strftime

# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
token = {"EAAFKVKHsjTsBAFvCVusn4Drd2l5BFfJKJKhoQRgW623E96lxekibwJLMIlSXIUl2IUhZAevlnfK7T2NZBMMW7Lil0ZCGxlUlnerEyoGvG5iipMO2JDbmJJyfad39yIjDDeBBul5d6ehWLE8byiCQPTjmxr5ZBAIZD"}

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
events = graph.get_connections(id="me", connection_name="events", fields="id, name, place, start_time, cover")

return render_template("index.html", events=events)
```

index.html:

```
{% block body %}
{% for event in events['data'] recursive %}
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="media border p-3">
<img src="img_avatar3.png" alt="John Doe" class="mr-3 mt-3 rounded-circle" style="width:60px;">
<div class="media-body">
<h4><small>{{ event['name'] }}, <i>{{ event['place']['name'] }}</i></small></h4>
<p>{{ datetime.datetime.strptime(event['start_time'],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0200').strftime("%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M") }}</p>
</div>
</div>
<p></p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Expected result is date formatted in flask loop according to chosen format (for example %d.%m.%Y, %H:%M) instead of ISO format.